# С какими парамтрами запустить Xephyr, чтобы добавленная в него программа изменяла размер в соответствии с окном сервера?

Tags: linux, qt5, x11, astra-linux

Запускаю сервер Xephyr строчкой с параметрами

```
Xephyr -resizeable -br -reset -terminate -dpi 102 :1 &
```

Затем добавляю в него программу, допустим Firefox

```
DISPLAY=:1 firefox &
```

Но при этом окошко может изменять размер, а программа внем имеет статический размер.
Собственно, с какими параметрами надо запустить, чтобы получился требуемый функционал?

Comment: *а программа в нем имеет статический размер* — размерами и положением окон занимается [*window manager*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_X_Window_System)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Актуально только для Astra Linux:

```
xinit /usr/bin/fly-wm --display :2 --rcfile "/usr/share/fly-wm/fly-wmrc.mini" --execOnly firefox -- /usr/bin/Xephyr :2 -autosize -resizeable -title "Моя программа во вложенной сессии"
```

Comment: а откуда флаг `-autosize`? это какой-то свежий xorg-server или собственный Astra'вский патч?

Comment: @Fat-Zer строку выдернул из коробочного fly-xsephyr.sh, тоже удивился откуда он. Без него ничего не меняется. fly-fm так не работает почемуто

Comment: без него должен по идее меняться по вызовы `DISPLAY=":2" xrandr` например... такое чувство, что `Xephyr` не изменяет размер экрана пока его не запросят...